# javascript: Add an object to an object

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following object structure:

```
var obj = {
    "51523":{
        "firstname":"Tiki",
        "lastname":"Pur",
        "age":25
    },
    "98741":{
        "firstname":"Nagasti",
        "lastname":"Bagamba",
        "age":20
    }
}
```

First - the reason behind this structure.
I want to be able to access objects inside obj easily, like so:

```
obj["51523"].age = 25
```

is there a way of adding a new object to **obj**?

Comment: sure, obj["11111"]= {}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use dot or bracket notation... `obj.newObj = {}` or `obj['12345'] = {}`

Dot Notation

```
obj.newObject = {
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "age": 30
}
```

Bracket Notation

```
obj['12345'] = {
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "age": 30
}
```

Comment: or using bracket notation like @juvian stated

Comment: indeed, thanks guys.I was close to solve this alone hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It can be done in several ways

```
1) Obj["newobj"]={"key":"value"}

2) Obj.newObj = {"key":"value"}
```

you can use Constructor function if you want to create multiple objects 
or can use Object.create() and add to existing object using 1 or 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to define obj as a variable and use dot notation to set properties equal to objects.

Example:

```
 var example = true;
 example.tutorialProperty = {
      aProperty: null,
      aBoolean: true,
      anInteger: 1
 }
```

If you wanted to cycle through them, then you could make a property that contains multiple variable objects.

```
 var example = true;
 var object_one = {
      property: true
 }
 var object_infinity = {
      property: true
 }
 example.objectArray = [object_one, object_infinity];
```

Now example has a property with the value of an array.

There's other ways to do this, but this should do for now.

Hope I helped!